# PhpStorm - Different FTP server for different Git branch

Tags: git, ftp, phpstorm

I'm starting to dev with PhpStorm and Git.
I've an host for my dev and one for my prod.
In Git I've 2 branches: Master & Develop

I'd like to configure PhpStorm to upload to the right host according to branch I'm on.

Is it possible?
Is someone could help me?

Comment: Sorry, not possible. But you can create 2 Deployment configs and switch between them manually as needed. Or you can have separate projects for dev and prod branches. You may also check comments here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25732

Comment: Why not put the work on git and deploy a specific branch to a specific server when you push to those specific branches?

Comment: @patricksweeney that's what I think and try to do but don't know exactly how to procees. I have my code already versionned on Bitbucket and deployed in 2 servers (prod & dev). Any idea to help me?